# Вывести сумму каждого одномерного массива из трех одномерных массивов

Tags: c#, массивы

Нужно создать массив из трех одномерных массивов. [3][ ].Заполните его значениями чисел от 1 до 10 рандомайзером. Вывести все значения массива (каждый одномерный массив выводится построчно в консоль). Далее нужно вывести сумму каждого одномерного массива, а потом вывести среднее арифметическое всех значений массива.
Массив заполнила, а вот как сделать, чтобы выводилась сумма каждой строчки, у меня выводилась сумма только первой, а далее он уже складывал все строчки. Я начала переделывать и уже забыла как было раньше.

```
        int[][] arrayOfarrays = new int[3][];
        arrayOfarrays[0]=new int[3];
        arrayOfarrays[1]=new int[3];
        arrayOfarrays[2]=new int[4];

        Random randomiser = new Random ();

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfarrays.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfarrays[i].Length; j++)
            {
                arrayOfarrays[i][j] = randomiser.Next(0, 10);
                Console.Write(arrayOfarrays[i][j] + " ");
             }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        //int[] amount2 = new int[3];

        for (int k = 0; k < arrayOfarrays.GetLength(0); k++)
        {
            int amount = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < arrayOfarrays[k].GetLength(1); n++)
            {
                amount += /*amount-*/arrayOfarrays[k][n];
                //amount2[n] = amount;
                //Console.Write(amount2[n] + " ");
                Console.WriteLine(amount + " ");
            }
            //Console.Write(amount + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: поменяла в каждом for на Length вместо GetLength (то есть будет arrayOfarrays[k].Length), стал считать сумму, только мне нужна сумма всей строки, а не каждая сумма после сложения каждого числа. Не понимаю как сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После того как сгенерировали массив, как-то так:

```
// общее количество элементов всех массивов
int amount = 0;
// общая сумма элементов всех массивов
int overallSum = 0;
// цикл по массивам
for (int k = 0; k < arrayOfarrays.Length; k++)
{
  // суммируем количество элементов в массиве
  amount += arrayOfarrays[k].Length;
  // суммируем только в пределах массива k
  int arraySum = 0;
  // цикл по элементам массива k
  for (int n = 0; n < arrayOfarrays[k].Length; n++)
  {
    // суммируем элемент массива
    arraySum += arrayOfarrays[k][n]; 
  }
  // выводим сумму массива k
  Console.WriteLine($"{k} sum: {arraySum}");
  // добавляем сумму k в общую сумму элементов всех массивов
  overallSum += arraySum;
}
Console.WriteLine();
// среднее арифметическое - делим общею сумму на количество элементов
Console.WriteLine($"avg: {overallSum / amount}");
```

И не надо путать многомерный массив `[,]` со ступенчатым `[][]`.
Функция `GetLength(int dimension)` - как раз для многомерного.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Помогло.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rnd = new Random();
int[] GetRandomArr() => Enumerable.Range(0, rnd.Next(1, 10)).Select(_ => rnd.Next(1, 10)).ToArray();

var input = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(_ => GetRandomArr()).ToArray();

foreach (var arr in input)
{
    // тут два прохода по под-массиву, но меньше кода.
    // Если упор на оптимальности / циклах - можно сделать вложенный foreach выводить в консоль + считать за один проход
    // То же касается и заполнения массива. Можно заполнять / выводить в консоль / считать за один проход
    Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(',', arr)}]");
    var sum = arr.Sum(x => x);
    var avg = (double) sum / arr.Length;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine($"Sum is {sum}. Average is {avg}");
    Console.ResetColor();
}
```

Comment: мы таких конструкций еще не проходили.